# Can RANK or ROW_NUMBER be used in summarized Netsuite search results?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I apologize if this question is a duplicate. Most answers I see were not related specifically to Netsuite search format.

I need to rank a search result by sum of amount, grouped by item. I tried ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Amount) but it didn't work. Any advice? Is this even possible in summarized search results?

[search results format photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtt29.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are aggregating the results (`MIN, MAX, SUM` etc) you also need to aggregate the expression in the `ORDER BY` clause, so that the results returned by the `ROW_NUMBER()` function match up with the summarized results of the rest of the saved search.  All you would need to do is add a `SUM()` around `{amount}`:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM({amount}))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Quick question. There are 254 results in my search. For some reason, the row numbers are inverted compared to what I expect. What should be row # 1 is showing as row #254. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM({amount}) DESC)

Thanks for your help! Sorry for the noob question.